# Links are not crawlable Lighthouse - Nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using [Vue Social Share package](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing) I'm getting only one warning in lighthouse "Links are not crawlable". Please guide how I can fix this issue. Following is my code

```
 <ShareNetwork v-for="network in networks"
                  :network="network.network"
                  v-on:click="saveInfo()" 
                  :url="sharing.url"
                  :title="post.title" 
                  @open="open(network.network)"
                >
                  <i :class="network.icon"></i>
                  <span>{{ network.name }}</span>
                </ShareNetwork>
```

```
//method
    async open(network = 'no network') {
    
        await this.$axios.post('/social-shares', {
          post_title: this.post.title,
          network,
        })
      
    },
```

[image]

Inspected code looks as follows
[image]

steps to reproduce this issue

1. clone the project from [this link](https://github.com/shanks25/nuxt-social-sharing)
2. Install dependencies
3. run lighthouse SEO to see this issue of `Links are not crawlable`

Comment: Please share your nuxt config.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zw4ci0d1f30rkbn/nuxt.config.js?dl=0 here is the config file

Comment: Please edit your question with some code as text rather than sharing a dropbox.

Comment: Hey sorry i tried to paste the code by changing some code to text as well, but StackOverflow is giving me a warning "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
"

Comment: Just to give you some more hints if I add ```href="#"``` to the ```ShareNetwork``` component, I am getting 100 SEO in the lighthouse but after clicking the share button browser is scrolling to the top of the page and I'm seeing # at the end of the URL  ```@click.prevent``` didn't work either

Comment: You're not nuking the whole SPA with this? Also, I cannot see any `href` in the package's API. Mind trying to share more code? Hard to help with just that.

Comment: A [repro] or github repo is also fine btw.

Comment: Hi I've updated the question with the GitHub repo link https://github.com/shanks25/nuxt-social-sharing . I've created basic nuxt application with this plugin, you can run lighthouse  on this project to reproduce this issue

Comment: That's just because the library renders anchors with `href="javascript.void(0)"` so they don't have target. It's actually acting link a button and should be a `button` tag IMO.
There is an opened issue on the github repo for this exact problem: https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing/issues/311. You should follow updates there, we can't do anything here!

Comment: yeah I did open that issue couple of days ago, But didn't get any response on github, So posted question here for an alternate solution

Comment: What do you have in your loop, what does it generate at the end (in `sharing.url` for example)?

Comment: its the url of the post that I'm sharing on social media ```sharing.url: process.env.NUXT_SERVER_BASE_URL + '/posts/' + this.post.slug```

Comment: @kissu can you check the GitHub project that I've shared, it has only one page, the loop generates icons and name of social media https://imgur.com/a/Iu4RHf6

Comment: Nothing more to add to this one tbh, code it yourself or ignore the warning pretty much.

Comment: Yes thanks, I'll try to figure out a solution